# How to read, analyze and save a video file in two separate Docker containers (OpenCV, TensorFlow)?

Tags: python, docker, opencv, tensorflow

I want to read a video file from disk, analyze it frame-by-frame using [TensorFlow Object Detection API](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection) (draw bounding boxes on detected objects) and save the output with bounding boxes as a new video file.

I have read that *it is generally recommended that you separate areas of concern by using one service per container* ([Docker docs](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/)) so I have created two Docker containers with the following tasks:

1. **Container 1** is based on `python:3.7` and has OpenCV 4.0.1 compiled. It is supposed to read the video file, convert it to a numpy array and pass to Container 2 for analysis. It should wait for the result and then write it into a video file.
2. **Container 2** is based on `tensorflow/tensorflow:1.13.1-gpu-py3` and has the Object Detection API installed. When running, it has the model loaded in memory. It should receive a numpy array from Container 1, analyze it and return it.

How can Container 1 pass the numpy array to Container 2, wait for the analysis result, write it into the file and grab another frame, etc.?

Note: I know how to do this using a single container with both TensorFlow and OpenCV but it seems that this is not "the Docker way"...

```py
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/path/to/video.mp4')
output = cv2.VideoWriter('path/to/output.mp4', cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('H', '2', '6', '4'), frame_rate, (frame_width, frame_height))

def analyze(frame):
    # TensorFlow doing its magic here...
    return frame

while True:
    ret, frame = cap.read()
      if ret:
          frame_bboxes = analyze(frame)
          output.write(frame_bboxes)
```

Comment: Use a shared volume to keep your files. You still need to figure out how the services will communicate with eachother though

Comment: This article may help: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-share-data-between-docker-containers

Comment: Thank you for the article. How would I efficiently use a shared volume? Should I `pickle` the array into a file in the volume? I'm concerned about physically writing each frame to the disk (thousands of write ops), it seems slow with HDD and lifespan-degrading with SSD.